# How do you undo/remove a sort in Delphi (XE3)?

Tags: delphi, sorting, delphi-xe3

For instance, I have a Case statement for a RadioGroup1.ItemIndex and when a certain item/ button is selected, it applies the following sort to a data set:

```
ADOTblModels.Sort := '[Model Name] DESC';
```

Now I would like give the user the option to remove the above sort (either using a TButton component or another radio button in the radio group), however I do not know how to do so. Is it possible to do this?  (I am using Delphi XE3)

Comment: You probably need to assign a new sort order. Did you try just assigning an empty string to the `.Sort` property?

Comment: No I have not, I will try this now. Thank you

Comment: The reference for the [`Sort`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.Sort) property says it clearly: *"Set Sort to an empty string to reset the recordset to the sort order originally used when the recordset's data was first retrieved."*

Comment: @TLama, please change your comment into an answer.